# ERROR : Property 'counterUp' does not exist on type 'JQLite'

Tags: jquery, angular

i'm trying to use counterUp() from Jquery in my angular project but i keep getting this error

> "the error saying in jqlite not jquery "

i  tried to fix it but couldn't  find any right way

i tried putting it this way(`< any>$('.counter')).counterUp()` but didn't work

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input,  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // HERE
  $('.counter').counterUp({
  delay: 10,
  time: 2000
});
}}
```

Comment: Angular comes with a lite version of jQuery called jqlite. It doesn’t include the ‘counterUp’ method. Native jQuery doesn’t include that method either. Not sure if you are using this library, https://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up2/blob/master/README.md, but follow the installation guide.

Comment: I’m going to add it as the answer then if you want to accept it that would be awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular comes with a lite version of jQuery called jqlite. It doesn’t include the ‘counterUp’ method. Native jQuery doesn’t include that method either. Not sure if you are using this library, github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up2/blob/master/README.md, but follow the installation guide.